# Matlab parallel for loop or Matlab open pool

Tags: matlab

I am trying to to some computations and I would like to do it in parallel using parfor or by Opening the matlabpool.. as the current implementations is too slow:

```
result=zeros(25,16000);
for i = 1:length(vector1) % length is 25

     for j = 1:length(vector2) % length is 16000 

              temp1 = vector1(i); 
              temp2 = vector2(j);
              t1 = load(matfiles1(temp1).name) %load image1 from matfile1
              t2 = load(matfiles2(temp2).name) % load image2 from matfile2
              result(i,j)=t1.*t2
    end
end
```

its works fine but I would really like to know if there is a way to speed thing up ... 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the size of each image file? One easy optimization is to simply move the `t1` loading line out of the inner loop.

Comment: the size is 240*320; did the t1 optimization but there is not much difference in speed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `parfor` loop and opening a `matlabpool` go together. Opening the `matlabpool` provides your MATLAB session with dedicated workers with which it can run the body of your `parfor` loop. So, you could change your code to something like this:

```
matlabpool open local 4 % or however many cores you have
parfor i = ...
   ...
end
```

Before running your code in parallel, I would definitely recommend using the [MATLAB profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f9-17018.html) to ensure you understand where the time is being spent running your code. (I'm a little surprised that hoisting the `load` into `t1` into the outer loop has no effect - the profiler presumably should therefore show that the `load` calls take very little time compared to the rest of your algorithm).

Comment: There is a drop from 132 seconds to 122 seconds when I shifted t1 to the outer loop. However, when I used parfor and matlab open I don't see any real improvement... and I get a message to fix the sliced variable issue in the code

Comment: Which release of MATLAB are you using? Also, am I understanding correctly that you have 16000 individual files each containing a scalar value?